# What are DRY, KISS, SOLID, etc. classified as?

Tags: design-patterns, terminology, methodology

**Is something like DRY a design pattern, a methodology, or something in between?** They do not have specific implementations that could neccessarily be demonstrated(even if you can easily demonstrate a case NOT using something like KISS... see [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com) for a plethora of examples), nor do they fully explain a development process like a methodology generally would. Where does that leave these types of "rule of thumb"'s?

Comment: DRY SOLID KISS... I don't know if that makes software design more appealing, or less...

Comment: Acronyms?  (Grinning, running, and ducking.)

Comment: @Warren P: That becomes GRAD... Hmmm...

Comment: a DRY & SOLID KISS is definitely better than a wet & weak slurp...

Comment: Marketing delivered buzzwords.

Comment: @JustAMartin Applause on your creativity ! U Created Anitpattern of Dry Solid Kiss -->Wet Weak Slurp!!

Comment: OOPS Basics (Encapsulation, Inheritance, Abstraction, Polymorphism) are the features provided by Object Oriented programming style. As a programmer, we use these features to create best possible object oriented designs (This is where design patterns come into picture). These design patterns help us to achieve SOLID, DRY and KISS principles

Answer (score 128, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it is a ***[principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle#Principle_as_axiom_or_logical_fundament)*** of software development.

In fact, Wikipedia refers to all of them as principles:

[DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

> In software engineering, Don't Repeat
>   Yourself (DRY) or Duplication is Evil
>   (DIE) is a **principle** of software
>   development

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_it_simple_stupid):

> KISS is an acronym for the design
>   **principle** "Keep it simple, Stupid!".

[SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29):

> The **principles** when applied together
>   intends to make it more likely that a
>   programmer will create a system that is easy to maintain and extend over time

Comment: Is there any good tutorial with examples that helps understand on how to apply these design patterns...

Comment: Design patterns are different. As the answer states, these are principles which should guide you in your day to day design and development. For examples and tutorials there are many in the web. Here is one such: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/11/solid-principles-with-real-world-examples/

Comment: Another opposite of DRY is "WET": write everything twice.

Comment: Stupid sounds harsh... Silly is better

Answer (score 20):

I'd say that they're basic engineering *principles*.

A methodology can have *n* principles.

And they're definitely not design patterns :)

Answer (score 8):

These are the **guidelines** for your everyday work, crossing the boundaries of layers, problem domains and technologies.

They also form what you would call a **philosophy** defining your professional practice.

Comment: And they need not apply *just* to software development - well ok, SOLID really only applies to software development but the other two are very general, and can be applied independent of any specific industry!